# Excel COUNTIF Function equivalent in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the query below i am trying to use the countif eqvilent fountion in excel to count the number of time each voyage_refence shows up in another column.
I tried using a count(*)  but its no returning what i need.

```
SELECT
  ABS.BOL_NUMBER, ABS.VOYAGE_REFEReNCE, ABS.POINT_DISC

FROM
 AMS_BILL_SUMMARY ABS
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SCE.EDI_TERMINAL_RELEASE ETR ON ABS.BOL_NUMBER = ETR.BOL_NUMBER
  LEFT OUTER JOIN SCE.NVOCC_JOB_HEADER NJH ON ABS.BOL_NUMBER = NVOCC_BILL_REF
WHERE
 ABS.TERMINAL_RELEASE_DATE > = SYSDATE - 14
 AND ETR.CONTROL_NUM IS NULL
 AND ABS.POINT_DISCH LIKE 'US%'
 AND NJH.MASTER_BL_REF IS NULL
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want a window function.  I would guess:

```
SELECT ABS.BOL_NUMBER, ABS.VOYAGE_REFEReNCE, ABS.POINT_DISC,
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ABS.VOYAGE_REFEReNCE) as cnt
. . .
```